# How to fix a problem with python packages in Atom?

Tags: python, package, atom-editor

I have a problem with python packages in Atom.

I tried to create for my python project two packages called domain and infrastructure. Domain package had a python module called business which had a class Plane.

When I tried to import from domain package:from domain.business import Plane , Atom gave me this error :

> File "/Users/codrineugen/Desktop/Fundamental of
>   programming/Project/infrastructure/repository.py", line 3, in 
>       from domain.business import Plane,Passengers ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'domain'

I don't know what to do . If somebody knows something please tell me .

Comment: Where is the domain located in the files?

Comment: From your error, it seems as if domain can't be found by python

Comment: The structure of the project is like this :   Project folder : domain folder : __init__.py  business.py , infrastructure : repository.py, __init__.py